# styling bootstrap calendar start and end dates using dateClass()

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am trying to style my bootstrap vue calendar so that start and end dates can be colored with a class when selected and then every day in-between has another class added to it called .inTrip I seem to be getting close but unfortunately it seems that when I add one class inside my function, it removes the others i.e. my start date can't seem to have both the start class and the intrip class applied to it but it needs to have both

here's a link to the calendar component https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/calendar

I'm hoping there's another way to write the ternary statement to include all the classes so they can't cancel each other out.

thanks for any advice I'll also provide an example for how it looks now, you can see that the lines for the .intrip class show, but if I click again, my .start class shows and my intrip does not :/

[image]

```
<template>
 <b-row>
    <b-col md="auto">
      <b-calendar v-model="value" weekday-header-format="short" hide-header nav-prev-year="disable" :date-info-fn="dateClass" @context="onContext" locale="en-US"></b-calendar>
    </b-col>
    <b-col>
      <p>Value: <b>'{{ value }}'</b></p>
      <p class="mb-0">Context:</p>
      <pre class="small">{{ context }}</pre>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'calendar', 
   data() {
      return {
        value: '',
        values: [],
        
        context: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onContext(ctx) {
       this.context = ctx
       if(this.values.length < 2){
       this.values.push(this.context.selectedYMD.split('-')[2])
       }else{
         this.values=[]
         this.values[0] = this.context.selectedYMD.split('-')[2]
       }
       console.log(this.values)
       
        
      },
       dateClass(ymd, date) {
         
        const day = date.getDate()
        console.log('VALUES', this.values)    
        return day >= parseInt(this.values[0]) && day <= parseInt(this.values[1]) ? 'inTrip' : day == parseInt(this.values[0]) ? 'start' :day == parseInt(this.values[0]) ? 'end':''
      
       }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
.inTrip{
  border-top:1px solid black;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
.start{
background-color: #2E9CFF;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border:1px solid black
}
.end{
background-color: #2E9CFF;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
border:1px solid black
}
</style>
```

Comment: After looking into it I realize I need 2 different class strings but I might need to change the underlying functionality of the component for that

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by adding values to the string using certain conditionals

see example:

```
dateClass(ymd, date) {
         console.log('date',date)
         let classText = ''
         const day = date.getDate()
         if(day >= parseInt(this.values[0]) && day <= parseInt(this.values[1]) && day!==parseInt(this.values[0]) && day !== parseInt(this.values[1])){
           classText = 'inTrip'
         }
         if(day == parseInt(this.values[0])){
           classText = 'start'
         }
         if(day == parseInt(this.values[1])){
           classText = 'end'
         }

        
        return classText;  
        
      
       }
```